# What is the difference between package and project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I don't really understand what the point of having a package is. Every Class is kept in a different file, so what's the point of using different packages in a single project?

Comment: In my particular Eclipse install there are 17 classes called `Event` all in different packages. If we didn't have packages they would all have to have different names.

Comment: I'm really surprised this hasn't been asked before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An Eclipse project has nothing to do with Java. It is a feature of Eclipse to organize and configure your different projects.

A Java package is a language feature of Java. You can use them to structure your project and control visibility between different classes. This becomes necessary even in relatively small projects, which already might have a few hundred classes. I suggest you look for a basic tutorial on what a Java package is and what it can do. To give you a headstart, here is what the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) has to say about the purpose of bundling related classes in a package:

> You should bundle these classes and the interface in a package for several reasons, including the following:
>
> - You and other programmers can easily determine that these types are related.
> - You and other programmers know where to find types that can provide graphics-related functions.
> - The names of your types won't conflict with the type names in other packages because the package creates a new namespace.
> - You can allow types within the package to have unrestricted access to one another yet still restrict access for types outside the package.

Answer (score 1):

Packages are useful for many things. For example, you could store a set of files that do a given task `TASK` in a package named `task`.

Packages are a way for developers to find easily and quickly a file, knowing what the role of the file is.
Whenever your project starts growing, packages are essential.

[See this lesson for basic understanding of packages utility.](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwji4ryblujTAhXC1xoKHeqjB38QFggiMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fjava%2Fjava_packages.htm&usg=AFQjCNH_gRfcrWhlBAztqvHW2B7a_vO9Mg)